# Directory Listing includes Date Modified, File Size into text file/excel file

Tags: windows-7, dir, directory-listing

I want to list an entire drive's (Z:) directories, subdirectories, and files in a single text file with all the dates and the file sizes. I can then open the file inside Excel.

I am currently using the following command:

```
dir z:\ /s /o:gne >text.txt
```

Is there any way that I can get an output similar to what you usually get with the tree command, with all the files and subdirectories stacked in one and not listed separately?

What do I have to do or to input if I wanted to remove other unnecessary information like the time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
powershell ls -r -fo Z:\ ^|?{!$_.PSIsContainer}^|Select DirectoryName,Name,BaseName,Extension,Length,CreationTime,LastAccessTime,LastWriteTime ^|epcsv Z:\excel.csv -En  UTF8 -NoType -Delim ';'
```

- `^|` - `^` - mask transporter/pipe symbol in cmd, `|` - pipe object
- `$_` - variable for the current object in the pipe line; sample:

  ```
  powershell 'a','B','c','d','F' ^|%{if($_.toLower() -gt 'b'){write $_}}
  ```
- `?` = `where` - check is not directory `?{!$_.PSIsContainer}` cycle `{}`
- `ls -r` - get all file in/and all subdirectory and current directory
- `-fo` = `-force` - add to list hidden, system and read-only attribyte file
- 'Z:\' - directory path, if use 'Z:' - set current directory at Z: cd.
- `select` - select properties at `ls` pipe object
- `epcsv` = `Export-Csv` - Export a PowerShell object to separated values (CSV) file.
- `-En` = `-Encoding` - Encoding string
     The encoding for the exported CSV file.
     Valid values are: Unicode, UTF7, UTF8, ASCII, UTF32, 
     BigEndian unicode, Default, and OEM. The default is ASCII.
- `-NoType` = `-NoTypeInformation` - Omit the type information from the CSV file.
- `-Delim ';'` -  `-Delimiter` char
     A delimiter to separate the property values.
     The default is a comma (,). Enter a character, such as a colon (:). 
     To specify a semicolon (;), enclose it in quotation marks.

result:
[image]

Comment: Oh it worked. I have to check.

Comment: @CharisseDaitol Excellent! Can change the output by adding and removing properties in the `select`.

Comment: yep, I've tried it. Since I don't necessarily need to show every property.Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The above has issues with spaces in directory names I found, this basic powershell command works better in my experience:

```
Get-ChildItem -r "Z:\" | select DirectoryName,Name,Extension,CreationTime,AccessTime,LastWriteTime | Export-Csv -Append -Path "Z:\export.csv" -En UTF8 -NoType -Delim ','
```

In addition using the Delimiter ";" is confusing to Excel and changing this to "," means excel can open the exported CSV without any further manipulation of the data.